# How to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin, to an XML which uses xslt in a different domain

Tags: xml, xslt

we are using a system which retrieves XML reports, the company that provides this report also provided an xslt file, that I have uploaded in an S3 bucket.
if the XML report is in the same Bucket I am able to open it and view the xml in the browser like a proper report.
However, if the file (xml) is downloaded into local machine or while it is in the other system, the browser will display the below error

[image: CORSS blocked in browser]

The learn more link points to the following documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin

Do I need to add this exception in each individual computer/browser who will be working with this report? and how can I do this, as the documentation doesnt give the steps.
or can I add something in the XML from what I looked I can add a header that says to allow this cross origen, however, nothing i do has work. The first lines of the XML looks like this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="https://ch-template.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/.....xslt"?>
<response xmlns:vs="http://vedaxml.com/vxml2/vedascore-apply-v2-0.xsd" response-type="report">
    <product-header>
        <enquiry-id>
            210222-xxx-xxx
        </enquiry-id>
        <datetime-requested>
            2021-02-22T14:10:43.102+11:00
        </datetime-requested>
        <datetime-generated>
            2021-02-22T14:10:44.163+11:00
        </datetime-generated>
        <client-reference>
            0066.....
        </client-reference>
        <operator-id>
            0056....
        </operator-id>
        <operator-name>
            XXXX
        </operator-name>
        <product-name>
            VedaScore Apply®
        </product-name>
        <permission-type code="X">
            CONSUMER
        </permission-type>
        <product-data-level code="N">
            Negative
        </product-data-level>
        <product-version>
            2.0
        </product-version>
    </product-header>
    <product-data>
        <enquiry-report>
```

Comment: See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/enabling-cors-examples.html. you need to add that policy to your bucket

Comment: Cool, yeah i add the following JSON in it: [{"AllowedHeaders":["*"],"AllowedMethods":["GET"],"AllowedOrigins":["*"],"ExposeHeaders":[]}], I couldnt find much documentation about AllowedOrigins and ExposeHeaders, my guess is that if the file is download locally will be better to have that wildcard *

Comment: @KevinBrown, when tested in firefox I can open the file but chrome and edge seems to have the same issue still blocking the template, is there anything in the CORS that I might be missing, the xlst file is in a different bucket to where the xml file is (the bucket only have this template and I have to set it up to be public for both bucket and file in order to allow this to work), does the bucket of the xml will require also the same config for the CORS? any security issues by doing this?